# Read .csv from PowerShell using ODBC

Tags: powershell, csv, odbc, connection-string

I am trying to use PowerShell to read .csv files, but get an error:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

This is my code and I seem unable to resolve the issue:

```
$SourceFolder = [String]::Format("{0}\Data\Source\", ".")
$driver = "Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt;*.csv)"
$connectionString = [String]::Format("Driver={0};Dbq={1};Extensions=csv,txt;", $driver, $SourceFolder)
$odbcConnection = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection($connectionString)
$odbcConnection.Open()
```

`Get-OdbcDriver -Name "Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)"` shows the correct driver

```
Name      : Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)
Platform  : 64-bit
Attribute : {[SQLLevel, 0], [APILevel, 1], [Setup, C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\VFS\ProgramFilesCommonX64\Microsoft Shared\Office16\ACEODTXT.DLL], [FileUsage, 2]…}
```

I also tried creating a schema.ini, although that seems to become relevant at a later point and does not affect this error.
I already restarted a couple of times.
Specifying the driver within `{}` makes no difference.
Using the `.csv` filename for `Dbq` instead of the directory makes no difference. Instead of a relative path, an absolute path produced the same error.

It seems to work when using a DSN, I would like to prevent that.

Comment: Try with an absolute path instead: `$SourceFolder = Join-Path $PWD Data\Source`

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. Initially I hoped it had to do with spaces, but that makes no difference, I get the same error.

Comment: When I create a DSN "CSV Files" then it works as expected, however I hoped it would work without it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a typo in the `$driver` the correct name is:

> Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)

The separator between the extensions in the Driver name is **,** (comma) instead of **;** (semicolon).